# DELETE FROM table get stuck in SQL Server CE

Tags: sql-server-ce, compact-framework, windows-embedded-compact, sql-server-ce-3.5

I have a Compact Framework application where I run this code:

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;

cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Empresa";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The `Empresa` table has only 187 records, but that instruction runs for over 4 minutes, which is abnormal.

Is there a way to optimize it? This table only has 2 columns. One of them is the identity. If I try adding WHERE id > 0 to the query, the same happens.

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: What build version of SQL CE 3.5 do you use?

Comment: How can I know it? I can get version of System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll which is 3.5.5386.0. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I have deployed the applicastion to a handheld device and it took 24 minutes to delete 187 records!!!! it is impossible!

Comment: You should use the latest build: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2017/01/downloading-sql-server-compact-35-sp2.html

Comment: DELETE is to be known of being very slow. As we do not have TRUNCATE TABLE, which is much faster, in SqlCE, you may use DROP TABLE and create a new one from scratch. DELETE will be slower for the number of index fields. DELETE will not affect the identity column. Using DROP etc. you will loose the identity values.

Comment: it seems that DROP TABLE is not compatible with SqlCommand. I tried cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE Table"; cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); but an exception is shown